# Issue with splitting a string

Tags: string, split, compare

For some reason, I can't get the split function to work.
I'm trying to compare the second word in the action string to the target string. What am I doing wrong?

```
String action = "Test Hello";
String target = "Hello";

void setup() {
}
void draw() {
  String[] split = split(action, ' ');
  String newScene = split[1];
  boolean result = (newScene == target);
  println("is " + newScene + " == " + target + ": " + result);
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Java / Processing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java way of doing this:

```java
String action = "Test Hello";
String target = "Hello";

if (action.split(" ")[1].equals(target)) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```